# Can you determine if Wifi security is enabled on network you're connected to on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, security, ipad, wifi

In my iOS app, I'd like to be able to determine whether the Wifi network the device is currently connected to has Wifi security of some sort enabled (wep, wpa, etc).

[CaptiveNetwork](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html) provides the SSID of the connected network, but not much else.

Is there an ***approved*** way of determining if WEP/WPA/etc are enabled on the currently connected Wifi network?

Comment: While it's certainly better for your users to use secured networks, it's definitely better that you ensure the privacy of your communications by encrypting your own data rather than relying on the network's encryption.

Comment: Perhaps try communicating with the router?

Answer (score 2):

Apple is not providing any Wifi related API and all the information that is available to you is given by the actual network, so basically you cant access this information.