# Swift - get wifi security type

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is there any way to detect if the wifi connection is secured using swift? is it possible to get the type security on the wifi? wpa, wep etc.

I get the ssid name in this way:

```
func getWiFiSsid() -> String? {

var ssid: String?

if let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() as NSArray?
   for interface in interfaces {
       if let interfaceInfo = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interface as! CFString) as NSDictionary? {           
                ssid = interfaceInfo[kCNNetworkInfoKeySSID as String] as? String
                break
       }
   }
}
return ssid
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: i need for ad iphone app, corewlan is only for osx.

Comment: Any luck @Gianluca ? I have to do the same

Comment: have you checked this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030561/can-you-determine-if-wifi-security-is-enabled-on-network-youre-connected-to-on

Comment: can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715055/how-to-get-available-wifi-network-name-in-ios-using-swift

Answer (score 2):

Some of Apple's frameworks are out of reach of the everyday AppStore developer. These frameworks are namely `private frameworks`.

They are present inside iOS but just not documented like the other frameworks(CoreLocation, UIKit, etc.). With reverse engineering methods, one can learn how to use those frameworks but most importantly, since they're **forbidden** of use, if you submit an app which makes use of a private framework to the AppStore, it will surely be **rejected**!

The API for extracting Wi-Fi security type is included in a private framework; therefore you can't use it an AppStore app.

Although if you want to experiment with private frameworks, for personal usage, you can visit [here](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers) where you will find the whole list of the private frameworks.

Keep in mind that their usage is not straightforward. If you want a starter, here is [BeeTee](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee), which demonstrates how to make use of the private framework `BluetoothManager`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `NEHotspotNetwork` in iOS15.

```
NEHotspotNetwork.fetchCurrent { network in
   print(network.securityType)
}
```

Comment: NEHotspotNetwork can't distinguish between WPA2 and WPA3.

Comment: Is there any other more precise framework?

Comment: on MacOS, we can use CWInterface but we can't use this on iOS...

Comment: @unobatbayar You can use `isSecure` to check it. As [Secure access to wireless networks](https://support.apple.com/guide/security/secure-access-to-wireless-networks-sec8a67fa93d/web),  security of WPA/WPA2 is `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible to get WiFi(current connected) security in CNCopySupportedInterfaces

Go to see the detail:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/342349#342349